# Subscribe to final observable after all observable completed?

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10, rxjs-observables

I have this logic here, which creates many observable and executes a call back after each of them is done.

```
from(rows).pipe(
    concatMap(row => this.uploadItem(row))
).subscribe(response => {
    this.currentRowNode.data.uploadStatus = UploadStatus.Success;
    this.currentRowNode.data.cmsRowId = response.responsePayload.cmsRowId
    this.currentRowNode.setData(this.currentRowNode.data);
});

currentRowNode: RowNode;
uploadItem(rowNode: RowNode): Observable<any> {
    this.currentRowNode = rowNode;
    rowNode.data.uploadStatus = UploadStatus.Uploading;
    rowNode.updateData(rowNode.data);
    return this.importService.uploadItem(rowNode.data)
 }
```

My issue here is that I'd like to be able to subscribe to something that would tell me `uploadItem` has been called for each of the `rows`

Where would that go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an observable like this

```
const final$ = of("completed");
```

And using rxjs **concat** operator, concat it with the existing observable like this.

```
const myobs$ = from(rows).pipe(concatMap(row => this.uploadItem(row)));
concat(myobs$, final$).subscribe(response=>{
//your existing code here
if(response=="completed")
{
console.log('all observables completed');
}
});
```

Here I created an [example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ytfxgv?file=index.ts).